# jQuery text() not working correctly when used after animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

i i'm trying to do an animated progress bar, and i have this code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"><div class="bar-value"></div></div><button>Submit</button><img src="gif.gif" class="loader">
    <br><br>
    <span class="progress"></span>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('.loader').fadeIn(1200);

            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100);
            $('.progress').text("1%");
            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100);
            $('.progress').text("2%");
            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100);
            $('.progress').text("3%");
        }); 
});
```

The problem is that text() only change when all animations have finished so, you can't see (1%), (2%), (3%), etc, you just see (3%) when the three animations finish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: animate takes a callback when animation is finished http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it changes the text before the animation starts, if you want something to happen after an animation use the animation callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('.loader').fadeIn(1200);

            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100, function(){ 
                $('.progress').text("1%");
            });
            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100, function(){ 
                $('.progress').text("2%");
            });
            $('.bar-value').animate({width: '+=1%'},100, function(){ 
                $('.progress').text("3%");
            });
        }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sVDb7/